# Aligning text to icon within a button

Tags: html, css, flexbox, styled-components

I have created a button, that includes a bin icon and the word "Remove" - the icon should set to the left with the text and the same height inside the black button. Whatever I seem to try doesn't work, can anyone advise where I am going wrong??

Here's a simplified fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/1q5s0cg8/13/

```css
.btn {
  background-color: rgb(39, 40, 42);
  border-radius: 0px;
  height: 48px;
  width: 112px;
  margin-left: 12px;
}

.icon {
  background-color: red;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
}

span {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <span>Remove</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The icon will need to be displayed inline (in this case, `inline-block`) and set `vertical-align: middle` to align the two element vertically.

The problem was that `div` elements use display `block` by default, which always takes up the entire line and pushes other content down.

(I have also set the `.icon` to match the height of the `.btn`, assuming that that was a desired result)

```css
.btn {
  background-color: rgb(39, 40, 42);
  border-radius: 0px;
  height: 48px;
  width: 112px;
  margin-left: 12px;
}

.icon {
  background-color: red;
  /* Removed this height: */
  /* height: 32px; */ 
  width: 32px;
  
  /* New styles: */
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}

span {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <span>Remove</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this.

- Using `display: inline-block;` on the elements you want to show side by side.
- Using `display: flex`; which I find quite easy to use.

**1** - Here is one using `display: inline-block;`. In this case, the styling to display items side by side will be applied to the items themselves.

```css
.btn {
  background-color: rgb(39, 40, 42);
  border-radius: 0px;
  height: 48px;
  width: 112px;
  margin-left: 12px;
}

.icon {
  background-color: red;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

span {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <span>Remove</span>
</div>
```

**2** - Here is one using `display: flex;`. Whereas in this case flex styling will be applied to the parent of both elements.

```css
.btn {
  background-color: rgb(39, 40, 42);
  border-radius: 0px;
  height: 48px;
  width: 112px;
  margin-left: 12px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.icon {
  background-color: red;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
}

span {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <span>Remove</span>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle with display: inline-block**](https://jsfiddle.net/czsojr64/1/)

[**Fiddle with display: flex**](https://jsfiddle.net/czsojr64/2/)